# Problems in making a Word Counter using the substr method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Word Counter with the use of `substr` method.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <input id="counter" type="text" /><br />
  <p>Words:</p>
  <p id="wrdCounter"></p>

  <button onclick="countMe()">Press to Count</button>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function countMe() {
  var counter = document.getElementById("counter").value;
  var wrdCounter = document.getElementById("wrdCounter").innerHTML;

  for (var i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
    var currentCharacter = counter.substr(i, 1);
    var nextCharacter = counter.substr(i + 1, 1);

    if (
      currentCharacter == " " &&
      (nextCharacter == "a" ||
        "A" ||
        "b" ||
        "B" ||
        "c" ||
        "C" ||
        "d" ||
        "D" ||
        "e" ||
        "E" ||
        "f" ||
        "F" ||
        "g" ||
        "G" ||
        "h" ||
        "H" ||
        "i" ||
        "I" ||
        "j" ||
        "J" ||
        "k" ||
        "K" ||
        "l" ||
        "L" ||
        "m" ||
        "M" ||
        "n" ||
        "N" ||
        "o" ||
        "O" ||
        "p" ||
        "P" ||
        "q" ||
        "Q" ||
        "r" ||
        "R" ||
        "s" ||
        "S" ||
        "t" ||
        "T" ||
        "u" ||
        "U" ||
        "v" ||
        "V" ||
        "w" ||
        "W" ||
        "x" ||
        "X" ||
        "y" ||
        "Y" ||
        "z" ||
        "Z")
    ) {
      wrdCounter++;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know where the problem is. I want it to count how many words there are entered in the input by counting the *spaces* after the last letter of a word and not counting spammed *space*. I also included lowercaps and uppercaps in the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nextCharacter == "a" || "A"
```

treats `nextCharacter == "a"` and `"A"` as *individual* boolean statements and then looks to see if either of them are `true`. That's not what you're looking for. You want something like:

```
nextCharacter == "a" || nextCharacter == "A"
```

Of course, that makes your if statement huge, which is also probably undesirable. Because you want the search to be case insensitive, I'd recommend combining all the lowercase characters into a single string and checking if the lowercase version of `nextCharacter` is in that string, like so:

```
if(currentCharacter == " " && "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".indexOf(nextCharacter.toLowerCase()) > -1){
    wrdCounter++;
}
```

This is much shorter and easier to digest. That being said, this whole function can actually be written in a single line like this:

```
document.getElementById("wrdCounter").innerHTML = document.getElementById('counter').value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim().split(' ').length;
```

`replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` is a [regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) replacement that replaces all consecutive whitespaces with a single space, `trim()` makes sure there are no spaces at the beginning or the end, `split(' ')` separates the string into an array of strings using a space as the separator, and `length` tells us how many values are in that array.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write this:

```
(nextCharacter == "a" || "A" || ... || "Z")
```

Instead, you should write:

```
(nextCharacter == "a" || nextCharacter == "A" || ... || nextCharacter == "Z")
```

Every operand of the `||` operator is taken to be a boolean value. The boolean value of `"A"` or `"Z"` is `true`, in JavaScript. Therefore, the result of `"A" || "Z"` is always `true`, and that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but it will make your if statement huge. While the user won't care, you as the programmer might. You can achieve the same effect with way less code. Please see my answer for further details.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler code:

```
function countMe() {
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    var words = counter.value.split(' ');
    var wrdCounter = document.getElementById('wrdCounter');
    wrdCounter.textContent = words.length;
}
```

EDIT:

According to Aaron Plocharczyk's suggestion, the code bellow would handle consecutive whitespaces:

```
function countMe() {
    document.getElementById('wrdCounter').textContent = document.getElementById('counter').value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim().split(' ').length;
}
```

Comment: And even simpler: document.getElementById('wrdCounter').textContent = document.getElementById('counter').value.split(' ').length;

Comment: That doesn't handle consecutive whitespaces, but document.getElementById('wrdCounter').textContent = document.getElementById('counter').value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim().split(' ').length; does.

Answer (score 1):

in your code

```js
var wrdCounter = document.getElementById("wrdCounter").innerHTML;
```

, wrdCounter is not an object/reference, it's a primitive value.
so you can't increment it and expect DOM to change.

instead maintain a local variable for no of gaps. and at the end append it as innerText to

```js
var wrdCounter = document.getElementById("wrdCounter")
```

.

i used local variable because it's bad practise to update DOM inside a for loop , always try to do Batch Update.

here's working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-sammet-vmrsx

your logic for counting words can be improved by using inbuilt String method "Split()".. but i am leaving for you to optimize it.